# Flutter launcher icons fails because --sound-null-safety missing

Tags: flutter, dart, icons, dart-null-safety

I am trying to create icons for my app using `flutter_launcher_icons`, with options defined in `pubspec.yaml`. When I run `flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main`, I get the following error:

```
Unable to spawn isolate: error: Library 'file:///Users/cameron/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_launcher_icons-0.9.0/bin/main.dart' was compiled with sound null safety (in strong mode) and it requires --sound-null-safety option at runtime
pub finished with exit code 1
```

Even if I pass in `--sound-null-safety`, the error persists (I also tried '--no-sound-null-safety' which also did nothing).

To check it wasn't a configuration error, I ran `flutter create <name>`, added `flutter_launcher_icons:`  to dev dependencies (and `flutter pub get`), ran the same command and got the same error.

I am on Flutter 2.2, and I depend on `integration_test`, so I can't downgrade to a pre-null-safety version of `flutter_launcher_icons`, because those versions have transitive dependencies that conflict with `integration_test` from sdk.

Flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.2, on macOS 11.4 20F71 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2020.3.4)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.57.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```